# function not returning value I want

Tags: c++

I want to be able to to take the user input and assign the given letter a value. I think I got that part down, now the problem is returning the value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int ch2n(string word);

int main()
{
     string inputWord;

     cout << "Type Word: ";
     cin >> inputWord;
     cout << ch2n(inputWord);
}

int ch2n(string word)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i != word.size(); i++)
    {
        if(word.find(i) == 'a' || word.find(i) == 'A')
        {
            total += 1;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

when I declare the total to 0, the return is always 0, but when I don't declare it, I get a return value of 229.... etc random number.

Comment: alternately, you could call `http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count`

Comment: You should just write the function `int ch2n()` above `int main()` rather than using a declaration.

Comment: I rather think your use of string.find needs rethinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't initialize it (set its value), using it is undefined behaviour and can return any random value - including 0

types without constructor, like `int` will just allocate space and have an undefinedd value, generally based on whatever happens to be in that location from prior use.

`word.find` does not do what you think it does, it is searching for `i` in `word`

You want to just use `word[]` :

```
if(word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'A')
```

Also, you might want to put `std::endl` at the end of your `cout` lines

Comment: When I type in a word for example, the letter a or the word Apple I still get the return value of 0 when I want to increment the value by 1

Comment: thats a different question :)

Comment: anything else, or is your question answered?

Comment: My question has been answered. I must say, this community is absolutely awesome. So glad I finally joined than just lurking from google search results.

Comment: Please feel free to upvote any answers that were helpful, and select an answer if you feel one was provided, and glad we could help.

Comment: I will do so, when I get the 15 reputation points needed to upvote :)

Comment: @user3200730 you can select an answer for 2 more and I gave you an upvote, remember to pay this back with quality answers

Answer (score 8):

I think `word.find(i)` is probably not what you want to call there. To access a specific character within the string, use square brackets, i.e.: `word[i]` instead of `word.find(i)`.

Comment: Better yet, use `tolower(word[i]) == 'a'` instead of `word.find(i) == 'a' || word.find(i) == 'A'`

Comment: @user2509848 thank you, that is much better than needing to use the or operator.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your result is random if you don't declare it to be 0 is because c++, and c for that matter, do not initialize data. If you declare a variable, like total, the initial value is whatever happens to be in that place in memory. It could really be anything. Always initialize the value of a variable.

I think the reason you're not returning anything meaningful is because you're using find wrong. std::string::find does not return a boolean, if returns a position. Therefore, you want to check if against a string position which says "The character does not exist in this string." That is std::string::npos. So, you will want:

```
    if(word.find('a') != string::npos || word.find('A') != string::npos){
        total += 1;
    }
```

Comment: `word.find(i) == 'a' != string::npos` will always result to true if `npos` is not zero or one. Since `npos` is not zero or one `total` is always incremented.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I meant word.find('a') != string::npos. It looks like he was just trying to iterate over the characters anyway.

Comment: If the text is "bbbbba" the result will be 6 because each call to `find` always succeeds since `a` is at the end of the string. You only want to check the character at the current location/index of `i`.